# Создать торрент файл

Tags: php, apache, torrent

У меня есть сервер Apache на котором лежит картинка. Нужно создать торрент файл, который начал бы раздачу этой картинки.
Мне не нужен торрент трекер. Я просто хочу раздавать файл с сервера.

Comment: Автор топика, вот наличие апача совсем не обязательно, а раздать можно только по торент протоколу, апаче вам не поможет. Вам просто надо использовать любой торент клиент, который так же является и сервером, с точки зрения раздачи. Он же как правило умеет и сам генерить торент файлы на основании директорий. Изобретать велосипед тут не к месту.

Answer (score 14):

> Нужно создать торрент файл, который начал бы раздачу этой картинки.

Три варианта создания торрент файла.

### Начнем с установки нужных пакетов в `composer`:

1. Установить [composer](https://getcomposer.org/)
2. `composer require coldwinds/torrent-rw`
3. Добавить в файл `require_once("vendor/autoload.php");`
4. `php -f your-file.php`

```php
   <?php 
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    // create torrent массив файлов или файл, 
    // URL optional: http://torrent.tracker/annonce
    $torrent = new Torrent( array('you-image.jpg' ), 'http://torrent.tracker/annonce' );
    $torrent->save('test.torrent'); // save to disk
 // На этом в принципе создание торрент файла закончено
 // если поместить его в директорию, которая доступна из вне, то
 // теоритически можно раздавать... 
 // практически придется выбирать трекер из возможных списков
 //----------------------------------------------------------------
 // Если хочется вывести в браузер информацию о созданном файле
  // get torrent infos
  $torrent = new Torrent( './test.torrent' );
echo '<br>private: ', $torrent->is_private() ? 'yes' : 'no', 
     '<br>annonce: ', $torrent->announce(), 
     '<br>name: ', $torrent->name(), 
     '<br>comment: ', $torrent->comment(), 
     '<br>piece_length: ', $torrent->piece_length(), 
     '<br>size: ', $torrent->size( 2 ),
     '<br>hash info: ', $torrent->hash_info(),
     '<br>stats: ';
   var_dump( $torrent->scrape() );
   echo '<br>content: ';
   var_dump( $torrent->content() );
   echo '<br>source: ',
     $torrent;

// get magnet link
$torrent->magnet(); // use $torrent->magnet( false ); to get non html encoded ampersand
```

[torrent-rw док](https://packagist.org/packages/coldwinds/torrent-rw)

---

Ещё одни вариант создания торрент файла `php: >=5.3.2`:

Команда:

```
composer require christeredvartsen/php-bittorrent
```

Файл:

```php
  <?php
    $torrent = PHP\BitTorrent\Torrent::createFromPath('/path/to/files', 'http://tracker/announce.php');

    $torrent->setComment('Some comment')
            ->save('/save/to/path/file.torrent');
```

[php-bittorrent док](https://packagist.org/packages/christeredvartsen/php-bittorrent)

---

Ещё один пример `php: >=7.1`:

Команда:

```
composer require sandfoxme/torrent-file
```

Файл:

```php
 <?php

 require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

 use SandFoxMe\Torrent\TorrentFile; 

 $torrent = TorrentFile::fromPath('/home/user/your-file.jpg');
 $torrent->store('your-file.torrent');
```

[torrent-file док](https://packagist.org/packages/sandfoxme/torrent-file)

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой способ: создать .torrent файл с помощью клиента на своем компьютере (имея копию файлов с сервера на компьютере) и указать веб-сид.

В программе qBittorrent это делается так:
[image: создание торрент файла с веб-сидом на примере программы qbittorrent]

После этого файл будет доступен к скачиванию через торрент с сервера с помощью .torrent файла, а так же будет распространятся в сети DHT и позже пользователи смогут скачивать файл у других пользователей сети, которые уже скачали файл.

Comment: возможно это автоматизировать?

Answer (score 3):

Делать такие вещи с помощью скриптовых языков несколько странно, ведь есть специально предназначенные для этого программы. Например:

```
sudo apt install ctorrent
```

Затем:

```
ctorrent -t -u udp://tracker.open-internet.nl:6969/announce -s example.tar.torrent example.tar
```

Эту команду можно завернуть в `exec()` если совершенно необходимо делать из PHP.

Это половина задачи. Вторая половина - раздавать этот файл. Для этого не нужен PHP, а нужно настроить консольный клиент:

```
sudo apt install rtorrent screen
```

Затем:

```
screen rtorrent example.tar.torrent
```

И `Ctrl+A D` чтобы вернуться в консоль. Ваш файл раздается на весь интернет.

Можно научить rtorrent автоматически подхватывать .torrent файлы из какого-то каталога, начиная раздачу. Кроме того, для rtorrent есть множество видов веб-GUI на любой вкус и цвет.

В итоге можно сделать так чтобы для каждого из файлов в каталоге создавался .torrent, затем автоматически раздавался. Apache здесь нужен лишь чтобы показать список .torrent файлов. PHP не нужен вообще.

Пожалуйста, четкий порядок действий, от создания торрент файла, до раздачи его по сети - прямо перед вами.

Comment: Это правильный ответ :) а то надо создать торент, но трекера не надо :) а надо раздать.. 8)